# Pyspark and Stata, losing variable observations

Tags: pyspark, stata

I'm experiencing a weird bug. I'm using PySpark in standalone local mode, calling Stata in each worker thread. Each worker then writes a dofile to disk, and calls Stata with subprocess.call, opening Stata instances that run the dofile. Each Stata instance then fetches a csv. **The thing is, the csv has 630 observations per variable, but Stata only recognises 621**. This doesn't happen when I import the csv from a regular Stata instance.
All dofiles have different names and the csv is only read by the workers, never written. Basically what i see is that when I run the python script, multiple Stata windows open (if I set gui) and start working.
What I've tried so far:

1. Running the dofile from cmd.exe **(630 obs)**
2. running the dofile from a .py without Spark **(630 obs)**
3. running stata from PySpark **(621 obs)**
4. re-running the dofile from the Stata windows generated in the Spark worker **(621 obs)**
5. re-running the dofile from the Stata windows generated by the Spark worker after closing one of the Stata instances launched by PySpark **(630)**

**So Stata only has this bug when called from pyspark, but the bug disappears when I manually close one of the Stata windows generated by PySpark in a worker.**

This is the command I'm using to run Stata, be it from PySpark or from cmd.

```
'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Stata13\\StataMP-64.exe -e  do c:/repos/myrepo/python\\script_n.do'
```

I only change the gui flag, and the n number depending on the worker.
This is the only call to spark inside the pyspark script:

```
with open(stata.working_dir + '/' + stata.csv_filename) as f:
    db = f.readlines()
db = str(db)
db_bc = sc.broadcast(db)
r_squared_rdd = vars_ranges_rdd.flatMap(lambda x: stata.call_stata(db_bc.value,x))
```

These are the last 20 entries from the csv file:

```
193,81,.0192107,.390009,.426966,.573684,4.64,.000926,.7859043,17.44954,1,0,0,5.93109,222.9224,329.5925,206.0276,246.3821,208.0373,210.31,375.44,244.42,221.05,.1525252,.0860937,0,0,0,0,0,0,-3.952288,-.9415855,-.8510509,-.5556766,1.534714,-6.984615,-.2409203,2.859313,5.406824,5.797857,5.32801,5.506884,5.337718,5.348583,5.928099,5.498888,5.398389,-1.880425,-2.452319,1.780208,,,,,,,,
193,82,.0240456,.330775,.468354,.563063,6.65,.0009732,.7912234,19.84998,1,0,0,5.93109,222.8613,353.4454,16.87376,271.7391,203.5503,222.12,385.04,265.34,225.8,.1519293,.0849039,1,0,0,0,0,0,-3.727803,-1.106317,-.7585309,-.5743637,1.894617,-6.93488,-.2341749,2.988203,5.406549,5.867729,2.82576,5.604843,5.315913,5.403218,5.953347,5.581012,5.41965,-1.88434,-2.466235,1.780208,.2244847,-.1647314,.0925199,-.0186871,.3599025,.0497351,.1288893,-.0039152
193,83,.0220034,.350189,.331897,.448052,7.94,.0009964,.7965425,20.1008,1,0,0,5.93109,232.6596,361.6682,226.0903,293.4129,230.9871,242.12,399.31,265.12,237.99,.0959471,.0836757,0,1,0,0,0,0,-3.816558,-1.049282,-1.102931,-.802846,2.071913,-6.911382,-.2274748,3.00076,5.449576,5.890727,5.420935,5.681581,5.442362,5.489433,5.989738,5.580183,5.472229,-2.343959,-2.480807,1.780208,-.0887551,.0570346,-.3443998,-.2284823,.1772964,.0234981,.0125568,-.4596183
193,84,.0171735,.342967,.640449,.442982,7.82,.0009761,.8045213,22.50491,1,0,0,5.93109,245.1605,385617,237.3293,324.3165,259.6269,254.5,420.93,268.27,254.88,.0559512,.0824713,0,0,1,0,0,0,-4.064388,-1.070121,-.4455858,-.8142262,2.056684,-6.931904,-.2175079,3.113734,5.501913,5.954844,5.469449,5.78172,5.559246,5.539301,6.042467,5.591994,5.540793,-2.883276,-2.495305,1.780208,-.2478294,-.0208387,.6573448,-.0113801,-.0152287,-.0205226,.1129739,-.5393174
193,85,.0180945,.356682,.576227,.38565,7.93,.0010006,.8085107,24.77798,1,0,0,5.93109,257.2078,398.3154,256.9071,361.1236,279.1209,263.98,436.96,287.89,291.84,.0742574,.0812092,0,0,0,1,0,0,-4.012147,-1.030911,-.5512536,-.952825,2.070653,-6.907135,-.2125614,3.209955,5.549884,5.987244,5.548715,5.88922,5.631645,5.575873,6.079842,5.662579,5.676206,-2.600217,-2.510727,1.780208,.0522404,.0392104,-.1056677,-.1385989,.0139685,.0247688,.0962219,.2830586
193,86,.0194505,.341006,.485,.407216,5.98,.0012105,.8071808,25.86566,1,0,0,5.93109,270.2549,443.5995,261.3926,303.6437,280.3852,278.78,453.32,329.18,322.33,.0712329,.0796638,0,0,0,0,1,0,-3.939883,-1.075855,-.7236063,-.8984115,1.788421,-6.716747,-.2142076,3.252916,5.599366,6.094922,5.566024,5.715855,5.636165,5.630423,6.116598,5.796605,5.775576,-2.641801,-2.52994,1.780208,.0722649,-.0449445,-.1723528,.0544135,-.2822324,.1903887,.0429606,-.0415835
193,87,.0235277,.266055,.588859,.423423,5.86,.0011789,.8138298,28.51783,1,0,0,5.93109,285.8289,480.1948,268.3836,365.0196,295.9352,295.63,468.26,337.88,348.74,.1105016,.0781939,0,0,0,0,0,1,-3.749577,-1.324052,-.5295685,-.8593836,1.76815,-6.743199,-.2060041,3.350529,5.655394,6.174192,5.592417,5.899951,5.69014,5.689109,6.149024,5.822691,5.854327,-2.202725,-2.548563,1.780208,.1903057,-.2481971,.1940379,.0390279,-.0202709,-.0264521,.0976133,.4390755
195,81,.0631212,.223671,.29148,.45,10.11,.0017569,1.695187,24.62795,0,0,0,37.4311,222.2222,289.8593,192.8789,293.2288,243.7925,290.6,388.05,237.91,233.3,.1227477,.0894729,0,0,0,0,0,0,-2.762699,-1.497579,-1.232784,-.7985078,2.313525,-6.34421,.5277932,3.203882,5.403678,5.669396,5.262063,5.680953,5.496317,5.671948,5.961134,5.471892,5.452325,-2.097624,-2.413819,3.622502,,,,,,,,
195,82,.0588861,.276907,.242802,.494071,12.57,.001784,1.705882,26.92453,0,0,0,37.4311,240.2337,299.8858,201.3809,299.9741,252.5526,302.15,400.63,255.39,255.62,.1209773,.0879057,1,0,0,0,0,0,-2.83215,-1.284074,-1.415509,-.705076,2.531313,-6.328925,.5340825,3.293038,5.481612,5.703402,5.305198,5.703696,5.53162,5.710924,5.993038,5.542792,5.543692,-2.112152,-2.43149,3.622502,-.0694516,.2135054,-.1827251,.0934317,.217788,.015285,.0891559,-.014528
195,83,.0573422,.231103,.310668,.449057,9.86,.0017866,1.719251,27.52601,0,0,0,37.4311,254.2064,328992,203.3134,332.2513,262.7839,328.69,419.8,258.78,269.11,.1181818,.0863571,0,1,0,0,0,0,-2.858718,-1.464892,-1.169031,-.8006054,2.288486,-6.327441,.541889,3.315131,5.538146,5.796033,5.314748,5.805892,5.571332,5.795115,6.039778,5.555978,5.59512,-2.135531,-2.449264,3.622502,-.0265682,-.1808182,.2464784,-.0955294,-.2428267,.0014844,.0220933,-.0233791
195,84,.0551157,.156901,.337522,.494681,11.19,.0019252,1.727273,28.82286,0,0,0,37.4311,264.6621,341.1911,212.6847,348.2738,269.8379,354,444.77,272.71,288.35,.111459,.0848282,0,0,1,0,0,0,-2.898321,-1.85214,-1.086125,-.7038422,2.41502,-6.252741,.5465437,3.361169,5.578454,5.832443,5.359811,5.852989,5.597821,5.869297,6.097557,5.608409,5.664175,-2.194098,-2.467127,3.622502,-.0396023,-.3872484,.082906,.0967633,.1265342,.0746999,.0460374,-.0585675
195,85,.0236432,.24697,1.56442,.478431,12.49,.0042988,1.721925,36.02775,0,0,0,37.4311,279.4814,340.6775,216.4476,365.8724,278.1635,362.04,459.44,283.4,309.1,.2716763,.0831767,0,0,0,1,0,0,-3.74468,-1.398488,.4475151,-.7372433,2.524928,-5.449429,.5434429,3.584289,5.632936,5.830936,5.377348,5.902285,5.628209,5.891755,6.130008,5.646859,5.733665,-1.303144,-2.486788,3.622502,-.846359,.4536518,1.53364,-.0334011,.1099079,.8033123,.2231207,.8909545
195,86,.030095,.208738,1.44186,.475806,9.21,.0043097,1.727273,38.39109,0,0,0,37.4311,297.3497,373.8318,224.5291,387.5402,292782,381.86,458.69,307.84,306.63,.1890332,.0813075,0,0,0,0,1,0,-3.503396,-1.566675,.3659339,-.7427451,2.22029,-5.446882,.5465437,3.647825,5.694909,5.923806,5.414005,5.95982,5.679429,5.945054,6.128375,5.72958,5.725642,-1.665833,-2.509517,3.622502,.2412834,-.168187,-.0815812,-.0055018,-.3046384,.0025463,.0635362,-.3626887
195,87,.0313973,.201397,1.67052,.470588,13.02,.0044592,1.745989,53.66693,0,0,0,37.4311,315.1641,377.9356,246.0614,411433,296.8684,392.27,480.79,303.11,337.28,.1561238,.0794507,0,0,0,0,0,1,-3.461033,-1.602477,.5131349,-.7537723,2.566487,-5.412779,.5573214,3.982797,5.753093,5.934724,5.505581,6.019646,5.693289,5.971951,6.175431,5.714096,5.820913,-1.857106,-2.532619,3.622502,.0423629,-.0358018,.147201,-.0110272,.3461967,.0341029,.3349714,-.1912732
197,81,.0178621,.158915,1.06098,.356322,11.35,.0008308,.8571429,16.64038,1,0,0,5.46081,183.1502,291.3753,151.3533,228.9377,156.9114,230.08,317.48,260.86,209.1,.0617284,.0806272,0,0,0,0,0,0,-4.025074,-1.839386,.059193,-1.03192,2.429218,-7.093133,-.1541507,2.811832,5.210307,5.674612,5.019617,5.43345,5.055681,5.438427,5.760415,5.563984,5.342813,-2.785011,-2.517919,1.697597,,,,,,,,
197,82,.0180711,.229167,.545455,.363636,6.64,.0009241,.8660714,17.61957,1,0,0,5.46081,194.2502,323.6862,151.1742,243.4275,171.5078,238.94,330.27,278.94,225.22,.1115789,.0798224,1,0,0,0,0,0,-4.013441,-1.473304,-.606135,-1.011602,1.893112,-6.986701,-.1437879,2.86901,5.269147,5.779775,5.018433,5.494819,5.144629,5.476213,5.799911,5.630997,5.417078,-2.193023,-2.527951,1.697597,.0116329,.3660816,-.665328,.0203185,-.5361059,.1064324,.0571783,.5919883
197,83,.0155747,.226667,.480392,.428571,7.77,.0010729,.8690476,18.90585,1,0,0,5.46081,207.1006,317.9891,154321,254.8656,196.4637,256.19,352.65,345.27,235.9,.1138614,.0790195,0,1,0,0,0,0,-4.162107,-1.484273,-.7331528,-.8472989,2.05027,-6.837371,-.1403573,2.939471,5.333205,5.762017,5.039035,5.540736,5.280478,5.545919,5.865476,5.844326,5.463408,-2.172773,-2.53806,1.697597,-.1486664,-.010969,-.1270178,.164303,.1571581,.1493297,.0704613,.0202496
197,84,.0136619,.204188,1.41026,.372727,10.11,.0011087,.8720238,22.70475,1,0,0,5.46081,230.2275,304.8781,170.5955,262.2378,192.6782,268.59,345.9,354.21,246.89,.1169591,.0782327,0,0,1,0,0,0,-4.293144,-1.588714,.3437741,-.986909,2.313525,-6.804576,-.1369385,3.122574,5.439068,5.719912,5.139296,5.569252,5.261022,5.593186,5.84615,5.86989,5.508943,-2.145931,-2.548068,1.697597,-.1310368,-.1044408,1.076927,-.1396101,.2632549,.0327954,.1831028,.0268421
197,85,.0130857,.180556,.830769,.333333,5.96,.0010541,.875,24.12361,1,0,0,5.46081,253.0364,283.4008,171.6738,271.7391,207.2574,279.17,357.84,354.78,275.01,.0810811,.0772219,0,0,0,1,0,0,-4.336235,-1.711714,-.1854035,-1.098613,1.785071,-6.855049,-.1335314,3.183191,5.533534,5.646862,5.145596,5.604843,5.333961,5.631821,5.880086,5.871498,5.616807,-2.512306,-2.561072,1.697597,-.0430908,-.1230001,-.5291775,-.1117043,-.5284544,-.0504732,.0606167,-.3663745
197,86,.012874,.112676,2.25,.244444,7.68,.0010879,.8809524,24.98198,1,0,0,5.46081,280555,324.3744,180.0927,312.2946,215.2698,306.09,376.54,355.64,294.49,.0757576,.0757007,0,0,0,0,1,0,-4.352546,-2.183239,.8109302,-1.408769,2.03862,-6.823469,-.1267517,3.218155,5.63677,5.781898,5.193472,5.743947,5.371892,5.723879,5.931024,5.873919,5.685245,-2.580217,-2.580968,1.697597,-.0163107,-.4715245,.9963337,-.3101556,.253549,.03158,.0349636,-.0679111
197,87,.0141928,.207595,1.18293,.360825,12.23,.0011857,.889881,25.95258,1,0,0,5.46081,314166,341.8803,182802,348.1432,212.8205,322.92,391.72,385.65,306.85,.0675676,.0741989,0,0,0,0,0,1,-4.255021,-1.572166,.1679944,-1.019362,2.503892,-6.737397,-.1166676,3.256271,5.749922,5.834461,5.208404,5.852614,5.360449,5.777405,5.970547,5.95493,5.726359,-2.694627,-2.601006,1.697597,.0975251,.6110725,-.6429358,.3894068,.4652724,.0860724,.0381165,-.1144102
```

All dofiles have the following structure:

```
cd c:/repos/myrepo/python
import delimited using data.csv

 log using 1_1366, text replace 

 qui regress county   year , 
di %23.18f e(r2)

 qui regress county   crmrte , 
di %23.18f e(r2)

 qui regress county   year crmrte , 
di %23.18f e(r2)

... more regressions ...



log close

clear

exit
```

Any idea of what can be causing this?

Comment: There is no detail here on the last 10 or 20 observations of the file (can you show them to us?) or on exactly what Stata or Python commands are involved. So, the claim of bug rests on an experience we can't easily replicate or examine.

Comment: Thank you. I've alredy edited the question. If you need anything else just say it.

Comment: I've looked at the data you've provided and can see nothing odd in it. I won't be pushing this forward if only because I don't use Python. But whoever does know about Python and Stata might want to know what's in the do file.

Comment: Good idea. Done. Thanks!

Comment: What you show us as Stata commands doesn't change the data. Sorry, I had no ideas to start with and I have none now.

Comment: Not the question, but it seems that (1) you have a fairly small data file (2) you're using Stata to do some regressions. So where is Python needed?  Why not just run your regressions in Stata? (I've attended several talks in which "I use Python to call Stata" didn't convey why people didn't just use Stata -- or for  that matter just use Python.)

Comment: Because the idea is to be able to run hundreds of thousands of regressions, using Spark to distribute these runs in a cluster. So i run a pyspark script in a main node, and then stata instances run in the rest of the cluster. When those finish, i combine the results. In this case im running a small amount in a local system. Dataset has, as i said, 630 observations, it's just for testing.
So why not use only python? Client says Stata has a high diversity of statistical functions. And those functions will be easy to add when the main functionality is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple. Because **the file was not closed before the flatMap**, the OS didn't give control of the last part of it to Stata, so it couldn't read it, missing the last observations of each variable. Closing the file properly before starting the Stata thread (by running the flatMap) fixed this issue.